# List all properties used for each object in a javascript script (or set of scripts)

Tags: javascript, static-analysis

I am looking for an easy way to (either programatticaly or via a ready-made tool) obtain, given a script or set of scripts, a list of objects used and, for each object, all the properties that where either set or consulted.

I mean to do this via static analysis, not via running the scripts, even at the cost of some accuracy (like showing a property that is only assigned in a `if` that never happens)

(this is an attempt to make a [question considered off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374291/a-javascript-static-code-analiser-for-javascript-meeting-two-requirements) better fit the sites requirements. Help in doing so is appreciated)

---

An example

Say that my code has a object `a`.
Some line of my code reads `a={var1:true}`
Another line reads `a.var2=false`
A third line reads `a['pineapple']='pen'`

There are also "gets" like `b = a.proper`, `f(a.cold)`

My program could hardly be expected to be able to say if a given line will run.

I'd be perfectly happy with the output "`a` might be an object and have properties var1,var2,pineapple,proper,cold", and even happier with "`a` might be an object. You set properties var1,var2,pineapple. Also, you read properties proper,cold"

I basically want to catch myself using undefined properties because of typos, not do any refined logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try F12 keyboard key while in your browser. In the panel that appears click on "Console" tab (see [Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS4SM.png)), and type the following:

```
console.log(window);
```

Once the "Window" object appears in the console log, click on it, and on the very right a Properties panel will popup.

Note: this "Window" object contains all the objects currently on the page, and you can access its properties through the Properties panel. You can console.log any other variable/object as well.

(works on chrome or mozilla)

Mozilla Developer Tools - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: I don't think this exists because most of your javascript data isn't available until runtime.**

*Why?*

This is because of how dynamic JS can be say you had an object `var a = { val1: true };` somewhere in your code there *could* be another line along the lines of `a.val2 = false;`, you can't actually get the model (or values) `a = { val1: boolean, val2: boolean }` without running the JS in some way or another to get the final potential structure of the objects.

Note: this is just one example of javascript's versatility there are many more, but I chose this as it is fairly straight-forward and it directly pertains to the question

*But it's an object?*

For anyone who sees this post from not a javascript background, an object in javascript isn't what you think it is: there's no strict structure to them. Javascript objects allow you to modify their internal properties (prototype) and their regular properties during runtime rather than at "compile" time (note javascript is interpreted, not compiled). Though you can mimic OOP object behavior with prototypes, but this whole sidetrack isn't directly important to the question.

**What *can* you do then?**

I know you specifically mentioned not running the scripts but most (if not all) modern browsers include a javascript debugger that allows for advanced debugging (breakpoints, expression values, variable values, etc.). Aaand as another answer mentioned `console.log()` is your friend.

I hope this helped, but if anyone knows of a tool please to call me out for being wrong: I didn't look around to find something that might do this.

Note: I assumed you were looking for a list specifically related to user defined variables, not the underlying object implementations of things like scope, arrays, functions, etc.

Comment: In this case, I'd be more than happy with the answer `properties used for object a might include val1 and val2`

Comment: interesting thought, it would be cool to have a tool that could give that kind of analysis of javascript... it sounds do-able, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's more to the problem than meets the eye